# Force SharePoint list filters to display alphabetically?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, filter, sharepoint-list-filter

Does anyone know of a way for force the top five filters for each column of a list (before you click See All) to display alphabetically?

[image: Screenshot of SharePoint List Filter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter panel cannot be modified with OOB or custom solution since it’s using modern UI.

I’m afraid it is not possible to force it to display filters alphabetically.

Comment: Disappointing, but thanks for your answer! Glad to know it wasn't something simple I missed. :)